# NumberFormatException for input string to double

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

In my android app, I am trying to convert a string value to a double value. But it throws NumberFormatException. The string value is "30.192781000000000"

My code is,

```
  String Latitude="30.192781000000000";
  double Lat2 = Double.parseDouble(Latitude.trim());
```

I have tried with this also,

```
  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US); // Looks like a US format
  double lat2=nf.parse(Latitude.trim()).toDouble();
```

But didnot work. Please suggest me any solution. I have to work with a double value and not a string value.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi Mahe, can you post the stacktrace? It's working fine with me.

Comment: This is working fine on [ideone](http://ideone.com/E9GDfL). Are the missing semicolon and `trin()` typos, or does your code also have them?

Comment: Working tell me the jre version you are using?

Comment: Yeah it is. Except if he doesn't really fix those syntax errors.

Comment: @Juned I am using jre 1.7 version

Comment: Post the stack trace....

Comment: Do you find out any solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code i think this should work.

```
NumberFormat _format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
    Number number = null;
    try {
        number = _format.parse(latitude);
        double _double = Double.parseDouble(number.toString());
        System.err.println("Double Value is :"+_double);
    } catch (ParseException e) {

    }
```

Thank you,

Answer (score -2):

> Blockquote
>
> String latitude="30.192781000000000";
> double latitude2= Double.parseDouble(latitude.toString());

Answer (score -4):

that isnt valid java code. try:

```
String latitude = "30.192781000000000";
double latDouble = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
```

Comment: Thanks. But, What makes the difference by adding trim() and removing trim() ? I am just trimming the spaces in the string if any.

Comment: I think his point is to add the missing semicolon in the first sentence.

Comment: you don't need to do that, parseDouble() does that automatically.

Comment: While this might be correct, it is exceedingly unlikely it is related to the error the OP is asking about.